# How configure Azure AD B2C in .net 8 Blazor Web App

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I tried properly configuring B2c in the new Blazor template in .net 8 (We have two project, Blazor Server and WSAM) but I can't.

I tried to follow some tutorials but they affected the oldest .net version.

Can anyone help provide me a working example of how to properly configure this?

Comment: You have mentioned Blazor WebApp and WASM.In which template you want to configure ADB2C. Blazor WASM / WebApp/Server App.Which template you are using [Image](https://i.imgur.com/lHadrGd.png)

Answer (score 0):

As we don`t have option for Microsoft Identity Platform in Authentication type, select it as None. You need to configure manually.

[image]

You can see the sdk of the app in the `.csproj`.

**Server** - `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`
**Client** - `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`.
Which is same in the Blazor WASM.

- The same SDK you can check in the Blazor WASM App(.csproj).

[image]

- You can get the sample code from above .NET 7 Blazor WASM app.
- The code will be configured with all the required packages.

***Check the below steps to Configure AzureADB2C in a .NET 8 Blazor Web App.***

Install the below NuGet packages with latest version in the Server App.

```cs
Microsoft.Identity.Web
Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
```

[image]

Thanks @blazorhelpwebsite for the clear steps.

Configure the User Flow and Identity in ADB2C by following [blazorhelpwebsite](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/55)
and [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
 "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://YourDomainName.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "Domain": "YourDomainName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc", 
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "{Your Signup policy}"
  }
```

There is an ongoing issue in the GitHub regarding Identity in .NET 8. Refer [Azure AD B2C and Blazor Web App Net8 Authentication](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50725)  for more details.